# iOS Swift Animation - Move image to the new position

Tags: ios, xcode, image, animation, swift

I am trying to implement this cool feature where the logo after the app loads  moves up slightly and the login view appears. The problem is that when I use this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
            var newCenter = self.logoImage.center
            newCenter.y -= 100
            self.logoImage.center = newCenter
            }, completion: { finished in
                println("Basket doors opened!")
        })
    }
```

The logo is moved to the origin place from the place I want it to move to. So in this example logo appears already with (y-100) and then moves to the origin X,Y.

Comment: Try putting it in viewDidAppear instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the view isn't actually laid out / on the screen in `viewDidLoad()` you shouldn't be trying to animate anything there. Instead, you should wait until the view is completely presented, which happens in `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)`. Also, I would recommend calculating the `newCenter` var outside of the animation call, then simply setting `self.logoImage.center = newCenter` within the animation call.